# Сегодняшний метеопрогноз (—) просто ужаснее некуда

Tags: орфография

Нужно тире?

> Сегодняшний метеопрогноз (—) просто ужаснее некуда.

Comment: Плюс от меня, в качестве компенсации)

Comment: По этой ссылке: https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL05/71827563.html (пункт 11) — тире нужно, т. к. между подлежащим и сказуемым нет никакого члена предложения, а _просто_ — частица, которая не является членом предложения. И в качестве сказуемого предикатив.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Когда дела идут хуже некуда, в самом ближайшем будущем они 
 пойдут ещё хуже. Джон Мерфи, Законы Мёрфи
```

Правильно:

*Сегодняшний метеопрогноз — **просто ужаснее некуда**.*

***Хуже некуда, ужаснее некуда*** и т.д.  Можно рассматривать как **устойчивое сочетание**  Разг. Неодобр. Крайне плохо. БМС 1998, 608.

Большой словарь русских поговорок. — М: Олма Медиа Групп. В. М. Мокиенко, Т. Г. Никитина. 2007. [https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/proverbs/47925/Хуже](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/proverbs/47925/%D0%A5%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5)

**[Розенталь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=92#pp92)**

6. Тире ставится перед **сказуемым,** выраженным **фразеологическим оборотом**: И женщина и мужчина — пятак пара (Ч.); А крыльцо — дай бог иному князю (А. Т.); Заработок у него теперь — будь здоров; Серёжа — седьмая вода на киселе и вам и мне.

**НЕКУДА,** нареч. 1. Об отсутствии такого места, куда можно было бы поместить или поместиться. Н. сесть, лечь. Н. налить, положить. **2. (со сравнит. ст. прил. или нареч.**). Разг. Выражает **крайний предел какого-л. свойства, качества** (обозначенного прилагательным или наречием). Завязал крепко, крепче н.
Большой толковый словарь